# React-Native Application hanging due Url loaded in Web view

Tags: react-native, webview

I am integrating Uber apis with my react native application. On one of the screens I load the Uber trip map in the web url. This shows us the map , source and destination pins as well as the location of the driver in the web view. This view constantly changes depending on the location of the driver

My application hangs while showing this uber trip map in the web view .

Not been able to figure our what could the issue be. If i load any you tube urls in the web view the application works smoothly. 
any pointers to solve this issue would be great

Comment: Have you tried using the `useWebKit` property on your WebView? It improves performance and in my case it also solved the issue of the web view hanging for some URLs.